# Percent area chart with missing data point has unexpected vertical lines

Tags: highcharts

Basic configuration:

```
$('#chart').highcharts({
  tooltip: {
    crosshairs: [true, true],
    shared: false
  },
  chart: {
    type: 'area',
    height: 650,
    zoomType: 'x'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    area: {
      stacking: 'percent'
    }
  }
  series: series
});
```

When some of the data in the series is missing, an unexpected vertical line and subsequent white space shows as in the following image:
[image]

Is this expected behavior?

Cheers.

Comment: I have broken it down and filed a bug for it at https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1991, will follow up.

Comment: Fixed the bug now, please find the patch at GitHub.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems this problem still exists in 4.0.1 when stacking is 'normal'. I've attached screenshots to the bug you had filed originally.